# Is there a way to store a matrix of million bits on FPGA?

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am working towards the implementation of a channel decoder on an FPGA. Esentially , the problem sums up to this :

1) I have a matrix . I do some computations on the rows. Then, I do some computations on the columns.

The decoder basically picks up each row of the matrix, performs some operations and move onto the next row. It does the same with the columns.

The decoder however operates on a 1023 * 1023 matrix i.e I have 1023 rows and 1023 columns.

Small test case that works : 
I first created a reg [1022:0] product_code[0:1] i.e 2 rows and 1023 columns. The output is as expected. However, the LUT utilization shows up to be 9 percent approximately. Then , I increase the size to 10 rows and 1023 columns(reg [1022:0] product_code[0:9]) which works as expected too. But the resource utilization has gone up to 27 percent.

Now my goal is to work get 1023 rows and 1023 columns. I does not even synthesize. Is there a better way to store such matrix on the FPGA ?

I would really appreciate any feedback !!!

Comment: Does the matrix contain only 1's and 0's?

Comment: There are many cheap FPGA devices with several million bits of on chip memories. U just need to use them efficiently.

Comment: What kind of method are you using to access the columns of the matrix?

Comment: Typically you would use an external memory, and read/write your rows/columns to it, so the FPGA only needs to store a row/column.

Comment: @AdhamzhonShukurov Yes the matrix contains only 0 and 1. I am working with a Virtex 7 fpga. My data is getting generated by a random number generator. So, even if I put my data into a block ram(I came across block memory generator which have depth of 1024 and data width of 1024), I still do not know how to efficiently derive columns out of those rows. DO you have any suggestions regarding that ? Also. will the above mentioned scheme using block memory generator work ?

Comment: @SushrutKaul Virtex 7 FPGAs have plenty of 18Kb and 36Kb block RAMs. But I think your design is using Distributed RAM.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the amount of storage an FPGA has from the manufacturers data sheet. However those memories are highly configurable.

Thus a 36 bit wide memory can be used as 36x1 or 18x2 or 4x9 units. Alternative you can read units of e.g. 36 bits but split the data yourself in 8 units of 4 bits. Process each nibble separately and write the whole back again.

Make sure your are  using **synchronous** memories as all big memory blocks in all FPGAs are synchronous. If you start using asynchronous memories, the memories must be build from LUTS and you run out very quickly.

Also beware that your row and column processing must take into account how the data is stored. You can e.g. store the data row-wise. Using nibbles as example: when you read one 36 memory entry, that gives you a row of 8 nibbles. But in column mode one read gives you the first 8 entries of 8 adjacent columns. So there you should ideally process 8 columns in parallel at the same time.

Comment: Vivado has a block memory generator which in Single Port mode supports data width of 1024 and data depth of 1024. Can  I use this for my application ? Also, my data is getting generated  using a random number generator. How do I extract the columns out of this data ?

Comment: Should do if 1 bit per matrix element is sufficient. Normal memory can not be accesses row AND column wise. I suggest you split your memory. e.g. 128 times 8 bits is also 1024 wide. Then one read gives your 8 column bits at a time. Address 0 give you the first set of 8 column bits, Address 128 gives you the  second set of 8 column bits etc.