# Finding columns in a 2-D array in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga

I have a following code :

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer: 
// 
// Create Date: 04/07/2019 01:20:06 PM
// Design Name: 
// Module Name: data_generator_v1
// Project Name: 
// Target Devices: 
// Tool Versions: 
// Description: 
// 
// Dependencies: 
// 
// Revision:
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments:
// 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  module data_generator_v1 #(
    // Define parameters 
    parameter integer MAPPING_NUMBER = 196  // MAPPING NUMBER IS USED TO SET A SPECIFIC PROBABILITY (16 BIT SCALING --> MAX VALUE = 65535 --> MAPPING NUMBER = 65535 * 0.03 == 196)
  )
  (
    input S_AXI_ACLK ,   // Input clock 
    input S_AXI_ARESETN, // RESET signal (active low )
    input start_twister,
    output reg [1022:0] rec_vector = 1023'd0,
    output reg start_decoding = 1'b0 ,
    output integer random_vector_bit_errors = 0 
  );

  // Mersenne Twister signals ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  wire [63:0] output_axis_tdata ;
  wire output_axis_tvalid ;
  wire output_axis_tready ;
  wire busy ;
  wire [63:0] seed_val ;
  wire seed_start ;
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Signals ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  wire [3:0] random_nibble ;   
  integer nibble_count = 256 ; // initialize to 256 
  reg [1023:0] random_vector = 1024'd0;
  reg sample_random_vector = 1'b0;
  reg [9:0] bit_errors = 10'd0 ;

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Generate numbers with a specific probability 
  assign random_nibble[0] = (output_axis_tdata[15:0]  < MAPPING_NUMBER) ? 1 : 0 ;
  assign random_nibble[1] = (output_axis_tdata[31:16] < MAPPING_NUMBER) ? 1 : 0 ;
  assign random_nibble[2] = (output_axis_tdata[47:32] < MAPPING_NUMBER) ? 1 : 0 ;
  assign random_nibble[3] = (output_axis_tdata[63:48] < MAPPING_NUMBER) ? 1 : 0 ;  

  // Generate a random vector ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  always@(posedge S_AXI_ACLK) begin 
    if(S_AXI_ARESETN == 1'b0 ) begin 
      random_vector            <= 1024'd0 ;
      sample_random_vector     <= 1'b0 ;
      nibble_count             <= 256 ;
      random_vector_bit_errors <= 0 ;
      bit_errors               <= 0 ;
    end 
    else begin 
      if(output_axis_tvalid == 1'b1) begin 
        if(nibble_count == 0 ) begin 
          random_vector            <= random_vector ;
          sample_random_vector     <= 1'b1 ;
          nibble_count             <= 256  ;
          random_vector_bit_errors <= bit_errors ;
          bit_errors               <= 0 ;
        end
        else begin 
          nibble_count             <= nibble_count - 1 ;  // 256*4 == 1024 bit vector 
          sample_random_vector     <= 1'b0 ;
          random_vector            <= (random_vector << 4) ^ random_nibble ;
          random_vector_bit_errors <= random_vector_bit_errors ;
          if(nibble_count == 256) begin 
            case(random_nibble[2:0])
              3'b000 : bit_errors <= bit_errors  ;
              3'b001 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 1 ;
              3'b010 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 1 ;
              3'b011 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 2 ;
              3'b100 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 1 ;
              3'b101 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 2 ;
              3'b110 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 2 ;
              3'b111 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 3 ;
            endcase
          end 
          else begin 
            case (random_nibble) 
              4'b0000 : bit_errors <= bit_errors ;
              4'b0001 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 1 ;
              4'b0010 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 1 ;
              4'b0011 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 2 ;
              4'b0100 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 1 ;
              4'b0101 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 2 ;
              4'b0110 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 2 ;
              4'b0111 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 1 ;
              4'b1000 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 1 ;
              4'b1001 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 2 ;
              4'b1010 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 2 ;
              4'b1011 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 3 ;
              4'b1100 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 2 ;
              4'b1101 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 3 ;
              4'b1110 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 3 ;
              4'b1111 : bit_errors <= bit_errors + 4 ;
            endcase
          end
        end   
      end
    end 
  end 

  // Sample output for the next block 
  always@(posedge S_AXI_ACLK) begin 
    if(S_AXI_ARESETN == 1'b0) begin
      rec_vector     <= 1023'd0 ;    
      start_decoding <= 1'b0 ;
    end 
    else begin 
      if(sample_random_vector) begin 
        rec_vector     <= random_vector[1022:0] ;
        start_decoding <= 1'b1                  ;
      end 
      else begin 
        rec_vector     <= rec_vector ;
        start_decoding <= 1'b0       ;
      end 
    end  
  end 

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  //  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //    // STANDARD CLOCK AND RESET 
  //    //output_axis_tdata contains valid data when output_axis_tvalid is asserted 
  //    // output_axis_tready is input into the mersenne twister and we can use this to accept or stop the generation of new data streams 
  //    // busy is asserted when the mersenne twister is performing some computations 
  //    // seed val is not used . It will start will default seed
  //    // seed start --> not used 

  // Mersenne twister signal assignment 
  assign seed_val   = 64'd0 ;  // used for seeding purposes 
  assign seed_start = 1'b0 ;   // We do not want to assign a new seed so we proceed with the default one 
  assign output_axis_tready = (S_AXI_ARESETN == 1'b0 || start_twister == 0  ) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1 ; // knob to turn the twister on and off
  // MODULE INSTANTIATION
  axis_mt19937_64 AMT19937(S_AXI_ACLK,S_AXI_ARESETN,output_axis_tdata,output_axis_tvalid,output_axis_tready,busy,seed_val,seed_start) ;
  //    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
endmodule
```

The focus of this question is the variable :**output reg [1022:0] rec_vector = 1023'd0**

I am loading this vector using a Mersenne Twister random number generator. The mersenne twister provides a 64 bit number that is then mapped into a 4 bit number. 256 such 4 bit numbers are generated to fill up one row in the rec_vector variable.

Now, I need to select each row in this 2-d array and send it for decoding. This is simple. I can write something like rec_vector[row_index] to get a specific row. 
After I row an operation on each one of the rows, I need to perform the same operation on the columns as well. How do I get the columns out of this 2-d array?

Please note that a simple approach like creating wires and assigning them like : 
codeword_column[0] = {rec_vector[0][0], rec_vector[1][0] ....., rec_vector[1022][0]} does not work. If I do this , the utilization blows up since now I am doing an asynchronous read on the 2-d array and that 2-d array can no longer be inferred as block ram since block rams can only support synchronous reads.

I would really appreciate any inputs regarding this. Thanks for taking the time to read this

Answer (score 0):

I'll give this as complete answer and not as a comment as a similar question popped-up a short while ago: [Accessing a million bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485946/is-there-a-way-to-store-a-matrix-of-million-bits-on-fpga/55487769?noredirect=1#comment97704769_55487769)

In fact what you are asking is "How can I access a 2d-array in row **and** in column mode".

This is only possible if you make the array completely out of registers.

As soon as you have *a lot* of bits, too many to store in registers, you have to fall back on memories. So how do you access rows **and** in columns in a memory?
And the answer is the very unsatisfactory: *"You can't."*

Unfortunately memories are implement in long rows of bits and the hardware allows you to select only one row at a time. To access columns you have to work your way through the addresses, reading one row and picking out the column(s) you want. Which means it costs one clock cycle to read one column element.

The fist way to speed things up is to use dual-ported memories. The memories on the FPGAs I know are all dual ported. Thus your can do two reads from different addresses at a time.

You can also speed up the access by storing two rows at a time. e.g. an array of 8x8 bytes can be stored as 16x4 and reading gives you access to two rows at a time and thus the firs two column elements. (But that has diminishing returns, you end up with one huge row of registers again.)

Combing this with dual-ported access gives you four columns per clock cycle.

Just as a last warning which is also mentioned in the above link: FPGAs have two types of memories:

- Synchronous write and a-synchronous read for which they have to use LUT's.
- Synchronous write *and* read for which they have can use the internal memory banks.

The latter have the largest amount of storage. Thus if you write your code to use the former you can quickly find yourself out of resources.